# Firebase error while resolving a bunch of promises: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I have an error from firebase while running a cloud function :

> FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError:
>   Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Here is a snippet where the error probably occurs :

```
    // const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    // const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    // const underscore = require('underscore');
    // admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
    // export updateSimilars = functions.database.ref('...').onWrite(event => {
    ...
        for (var i in callerFlattenLikesDislikes) {
            getOtherUsersPromises.push(getOtherUsersFromName(callerFlattenLikesDislikes[i], genre));
        }    
        console.log('getOtherUsersPromises length: ' + getOtherUsersPromises.length);    
        return Promise.all(getOtherUsersPromises).then(dataArr => {
                    console.log(dataArr); // will never fire
                    dataArr.forEach(data => {
                        data.forEach(user => {
                            if (otherUsers.indexOf(user) > -1 && user !== userId) {
                                otherUsers.push(user);
                            }
                        });
                    });
             ....
             ....

      function getOtherUsersFromName(name, genre) {
       console.log('fired getOtherUsersFromName: ' + name);
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        admin
            .database()
            .ref('/names/' + genre + '/' + name)
            .once('value', snapshot => {
                var dic = snapshot.val();
                var dislikingUsers = Object.keys(dic['dislikingUsers']);
                var likingUsers = Object.keys(dic['likingUsers']);
                var users = underscore.union(dislikingUsers, likingUsers);
                console.log('will resolve: ' + users);
                resolve(users);
            });
         });
       }
```

Basically, I have an array of promises to be executed asynchronously (the same firebase query for several input items).
I want to gather all the results before starting to process them.

But the `.then` after `Promise.all` seems to never be fired, and I have the following firebase logs:

[image]

Anyone to help me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to check a name exist or not at the path `'/names/' + genre + '/' + name`. It gives an error when this path is empty.

```
function getOtherUsersFromName(name, genre) {
       console.log('fired getOtherUsersFromName: ' + name);
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        admin
            .database()
            .ref('/names/' + genre + '/' + name)
            .once('value', snapshot => {
               if (snapshot.exists()){
                var dic = snapshot.val();
                var dislikingUsers = Object.keys(dic['dislikingUsers']);
                var likingUsers = Object.keys(dic['likingUsers']);
                var users = underscore.union(dislikingUsers, likingUsers);
                console.log('will resolve: ' + users);
                resolve(users); 
               } else {
                  // Do something as the path is empty
               }
            });
         });
       }
```

Comment: Thanks HakanC ! The name should normally exist, as it comes from this path... But I will check this...

Comment: `else {...}` must either resolve or reject the promise, otherwise it will remain pending and so will the promise returned by `Promise.all()`.

Comment: If you could expand the error `down-arrow` and check the error line. This will be more helpful where the error comes from.

Comment: Thanks Roamer. I have added a check on `snapshot.exists()` as described above, and I `reject("name was not found")` the promise in the `else` block. Then I `.catch(err => {console.log("err: " + err)})`  in the main function. But I have the same error, and I never see the "err: name was not found" printed in logs

Comment: @HakanC : OK how can I add this big amount of text in a comment ? Or attach a screenshot ?

Comment: I think problem comes ` var dislikingUsers = Object.keys(dic['dislikingUsers']);`   and `dislikingUsers` is not defined. or I could not find it. Also the same for next line. I meant error says `cannot convert empty or null`

Comment: @LaurentMaquet, you've probably got it right but just to make sure, the catch must be on the individual promises, not on the aggregated promise returned by `Promise.all()`

Comment: `dic['dislikingUsers']` is the same as `dic.dislikingUsers` and should really be written that way. Same for `dic['likingUsers']`

Comment: BTW, an error thrown from a Promise constructor will reject the Promise, so providing there's a `.catch(console.log)` on the individual promises, then you should see the error in the log.

Comment: Currently, my catch is on the Promise.all().then().catch... i thought it was correct...

Comment: French déjeuner ... that'll be at least 3 hours!

Comment: Huhihu huhuhu huhu... No I promise !

Comment: Yes, you can put the catch there too but it depends what you want to do. Catching errors on the individual promises allows you to inject some default value, say a `null`, and will ensure the aggregated promise goes down its success path.

Comment: Thank you HakanC and Roamer-1888. You put me on the right track. dislikingUsers and likingUsers could be undefined. So I had to check it like that : `if('dislikingUsers' in dic) { dislikingUsers = Object.keys(dic.dislikingUsers)} else {dislikingUsers = []}`

Comment: More economically, you can write `var dislikingUsers = Object.keys(dic.dislikingUsers || {}); `

Comment: At the end of editing your code, please edit above code also for the stackoverflow community. :)